# React.js Carousel Effect

Tags: reactjs

EDIT: The effect I am going for is seen on the Uber Eats page: https://ubereats.com/sf/

I have implemented a package to make it appear like the text is being typed on the page.  It looks like this:

```
Typing = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
      return { textIndex: 0 };
  },

  next: function() {
    // increment the textIndex by one
    this.setState({ textIndex: this.state.textIndex + 1});
  },

  render: function() {
    const docs = '#one';
    return (

        <div>
              <div className="TypistExample">

                <Typist className="TypistExample-header" avgTypingSpeed={15000} startDelay={1000} cursor={{show: false}} onTypingDone={this.next}>
                  { typedtext.map(function(t){
                    return <h1 className={t.id} key={t.id}><a target="_blank" href={t.link}>{t.text}</a></h1>
                  }) }
                </Typist>

              </div>
        </div>

    );
  }

});
```

I have a json array object that I feed into this:

```
var typedtext = [
    {id: 'home', text: 'home', link: 'home'},
    {id: 'something', text: 'something', link: 'something'},
    {id: 'dev', text: 'dev', link: 'dev'},
    {id: 'another', text: 'another', link: 'another'},
];
```

What I would like to do, is have it so that when a line of text is "typed", it stays there for a moment, and then fades away, making room for the next object in the array, etc... in a loop.

How would I achieve this with React?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably wrap `this.setState` with `setTimeout`

```
 next: function() {
     setTimeout(() => {
       // increment the textIndex by one
       this.setState({ textIndex: this.state.textIndex + 1});
     }, 2000);
  },
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not change anything with the behavior.

Comment: Hm... strange. You can also try this thing https://github.com/jstejada/react-typist#delaygenerator  `function(mean, std, {line, lineIdx, charIdx, defDelayGenerator}) {
  // Delay the animation for 2 seconds at the last character of the first line
  if (lineIdx === 0 && charIdx === line.length - 1) {
    return 2000;
  }
  return defDelayGenerator();
}`